# How to add css class to particular link in a group of links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have 5 links, I want to add `active` class to particular link.

For example

```
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="width: 200px; padding-top: 50px;" id="mySidebar">
    <button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()">Close &times;</button>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Create User</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Security</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

> If I want to add `active` class to second link(Security). How can I add.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //ADD Active in SideNav bar
    $('.w3-sidebar a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.w3-sidebar a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
});
```

I tried the above code. But the problem is. When page get reload. That active is not appearing.

Comment: If you want to appear this class after page reload you must save this information somewhere.. in localstorage, in cookie, in url.

Comment: @Dominikkrzywiecki no need. I got it. `$('#linkCreateUser').addClass('active');` If I load it at beginning, this class will have the active. It's worked. I don't why people are give negative. They should tell the reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the 2nd element with your jquery and apply the `active` class every time on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".w3-button:eq(2)").addClass("active");
  $('.w3-sidebar a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.w3-sidebar a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="width: 200px; padding-top: 50px;" id="mySidebar">
  <button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()">Close &times;</button>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Create User</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Security</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write below code

```
$('.w3-sidebar a:nth-child(2)').addClass('active')
```

check out jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9sncqbb9/

Answer (score 0):

There is few ways to do that. If you have information about current page just do something like:

```
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="width: 200px; padding-top: 50px;" id="mySidebar">
    <button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()">Close &times;</button>
    <a href="createUser" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Create User</a>
    <a href="security" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Security</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

and then in your JS code:

```
//currentPageName = 'security';
$('a[href="'+currentPageName+'"]).addClass('active');
```